# linux grep certain lines

Tags: linux, grep

HI I am trying to grep certain lines from .dat file and place them into a new file test.dat (or .txt). I want to grep the date/time (2012Sep212357) and the line starting with (FD12P and ending with PARS. Keeping in mind that the date/time after 2012Sep is changing. I tried

```
grep '^2012Sep.*AA$' |'^FD12P.*PARS$' file.dat > test.dat
```

But it is not working, the output should be:

```
2012Sep212357,FD12P_S/N ,      OK  ,  FD, 102, 26578, 16081, C,   0,   0,   0,     0.00,    41.18,    0.0,  0.000,  0.000,  0.000,  0.000,  0.000,  0.000, 15.20,      4, BEL_RAIN,      OK  ,  0.00, -0.20, -1.40, -1.80, -1.40, -1.40, -1.40, 311.0, ,          ,      0,0.0000000,0.0000000, Snow11_Icing ,   OK  , 33, 0909, 190, 17.03, 11111, FD, WS425_SN_,      OK  , 208, 210, 5, 5,  11.4,  11.4,  11.7,   5.9,   6.0,   4.9, 196.3,   6.4, 172.0,   3.5, 194.0,   6.4, 172.0,   1.8, 178.0,   4.6,   6.0,  0,   0.0,   1.6, CR3000_SN_,      OK  , "2012-09-21 20:01:30", "SN_1838", 12.90, 16.47, 17.06, 50.22,1001.1,  0.00,  0.00,2419.6, 432.1,   -4.6,   3.1, 188.5, S78D_SN_,      OK  ,64403.0,64841.0,  10.0, 211.5,   5.4, 206.5,   4.3,   5.4, 209.8,   3.2, 190.3,   5.4, 214.3,   1.6, 191.1,   3.8,  23.2,  0,   0.0,   1.1,
```

Sample of original file (I have many like the lines below in the file):

```
2012Sep212357 23:56:03.06250, AAA_YMDHMS, 2012, 9, 21, 23, 56, 4, POSS_71,      OK  ,  15.0,   73.2,   0.0,   0.0,   C,   0.0,   0.3,   0.6,PS711 78:218:17:41 189.9 205.5  112        1.7        7.3 60  15  51  73.2   0.0     2080,PS712,PS713,PS714,PS715,PS716 F# 51 2.03 7.39 54.98 2.06 0.89 681.1  0.3 11.0 112  14.6 C    376 0.00 0.00 0  0  2  1  112  1.7 189.8 205.4 157.1 192.0 78.5 32.0 928.0 2.0 0.0 -99.0 0.0 10.7 10.7 10000000.0 376 T 4 I 0 ,dia  2 6, 28 22 4,dia  3 5, 26 34 4,dia  4 3 18 17, 3,dia  5 4 25 13 4 1,,dia  6 5 12 7 1,dia  7 6 10 6,dia  8 5 12 4,dia  9 1 3 1,dia  10 2 3 1,dia  11 2 4,dia  12 0 0 1,dia  13 1 1,dia  14 1,dia  15 1 1,dia  16 1 1 1,dia  17 1,dia  18 1 3,dia  22 0 1,dia  23 1,dia  24 1 1,dia  25 1,dia  26 1,dia  29 1,dia  30 1,dia  31 2 2,dia  32 0 3,dia  33 1 2,dia  34 0 1 1,dia  35 1,dia  36 0 3,dia  37 0 2,dia  38 1 2,dia  39 1 2,dia  40 0 2,dia  41 2,dia  42 1 4 1,dia  43 2,dia  44 1 2,dia  45 1 2,dia  47 0 3,dia  49 2,dia  52 2,dia  59 1,dia  60 1,dia  61 1,dia ,dia ,dia ,dia ,dia ,dia ,dia ,dia ,dia ,dia ,dia ,dia ,dia ,dia ,dia ,dia ,dia ,dia ,dia , YANKEE_S/N_0706011,      OK  ,  46.9,  48.2,  -1.3,  17.0,   2.5, 1.000,  -0.8,   0.0,  -0.1,  -0.1,  -1.5,  -3.5,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0, CT25K_S/N_A42101,      OK  ,CT0,20,2,3,00, /////, /////, /////,00000300,100,N,100,25,82,206,-4,7,LF7HN1,6,-2,6,5,5,4,4,4,3,4,3,2,2,3,3,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,3,3,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,3,4,4,5,3,4,5,4,3,5,3,6,4,1,5,3,3,4,5,3,3,0,1,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, FD12P_S/N ,      OK  ,  FD, 102, 26578, 16081, C,   0,   0,   0,     0.00,    41.18,    0.0,  0.000,  0.000,  0.000,  0.000,  0.000,  0.000, 15.20,      4, BEL_RAIN,      OK  ,  0.00, -0.20, -1.40, -1.80, -1.40, -1.40, -1.40, 311.0, ,          ,      0,0.0000000,0.0000000, Snow11_Icing ,   OK  , 33, 0909, 190, 17.03, 11111, FD, WS425_SN_,      OK  , 208, 210, 5, 5,  11.4,  11.4,  11.7,   5.9,   6.0,   4.9, 196.3,   6.4, 172.0,   3.5, 194.0,   6.4, 172.0,   1.8, 178.0,   4.6,   6.0,  0,   0.0,   1.6, CR3000_SN_,      OK  , "2012-09-21 20:01:30", "SN_1838", 12.90, 16.47, 17.06, 50.22,1001.1,  0.00,  0.00,2419.6, 432.1,   -4.6,   3.1, 188.5, S78D_SN_,      OK  ,64403.0,64841.0,  10.0, 211.5,   5.4, 206.5,   4.3,   5.4, 209.8,   3.2, 190.3,   5.4, 214.3,   1.6, 191.1,   3.8,  23.2,  0,   0.0,   1.1, PARS_SN ,      OK  ,  0.00, 147.7,    C,   -10.0,   9999,  19.0, 10057,     0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, TB_SN_ ,      OK  ,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0, GEONOR_SN_,      OK  ,   1.1,  -0.1,   0.0,  -0.5, MP3000_SN_3031,      OK  , 13611, 09/21/12 23:52:03,   201, 290.8410,  54.5700, 992.6000, 224.9700,   0.0000, 13616, 09/21/12 23:52:52,   301,   2.006,   0.000,  -1.000, 13629, 09/21/12 23:53:40,   301,   2.153,   0.000,  -1.000, 13612, 09/21/12 23:52:49,   401, Zenith33, 290.841, 290.619, 290.324, 289.965, 289.594, 289.315, 289.019, 288.657, 288.252, 287.874, 287.473, 286.550, 285.484, 284.489, 283.557, 282.448, 281.549, 280.729, 279.510, 278.444, 277.386, 276.560, 275.714, 275.025, 274.243, 273.660, 272.269, 270.575, 269.615, 268.371, 267.229, 265.628, 264.201, 262.967, 261.651, 259.787, 258.405, 256.936, 255.301, 253.573, 251.715, 249.948, 248.309, 246.431, 244.513, 242.739, 240.876, 238.979, 237.113, 235.236, 233.310, 231.360, 229.586, 227.806, 226.248, 224.444, 222.997, 221.686, 13613, 09/21/12 23:52:50,   402, Zenith33,   8.112,   7.620,   7.356,   7.167,   7.001,   6.926,   6.905,   6.821,   6.749,   6.753,   6.634,   6.261,   5.949,   5.797,   5.612,   5.539,   5.345,   5.309,   5.308,   5.128,   4.854,   4.559,   4.412,   4.302,   4.119,   3.899,   3.280,   2.939,   2.634,   2.426,   2.251,   2.077,   1.768,   1.456,   1.191,   1.016,   0.836,   0.688,   0.572,   0.498,   0.420,   0.342,   0.315,   0.268,   0.247,   0.216,   0.169,   0.151,   0.117,   0.086,   0.079,   0.057,   0.043,   0.034,   0.027,   0.029,   0.025,   0.023, 13614, 09/21/12 23:52:50,   403, Zenith33,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.001,   0.001,   0.001,   0.002,   0.003,   0.004,   0.004,   0.005,   0.006,   0.006,   0.006,   0.005,   0.005,   0.006,   0.006,   0.006,   0.005,   0.004,   0.005,   0.007,   0.001,   0.001,   0.001,   0.001,   0.001,   0.001,   0.000,   0.001,   0.003,   0.001,   0.001,   0.002,   0.004,   0.001,   0.001,   0.004,   0.002,   0.002,   0.001,   0.000,   0.002,   0.000,   0.000,   0.002,   0.001, 13615, 09/21/12 23:52:51,   404, Zenith33,  56.270,  53.729,  53.026,  52.810,  52.940,  53.694,  54.346,  54.964,  55.335,  56.838,  57.384,  58.904,  60.251,  62.294,  63.354,  65.906,  66.386,  69.111,  73.093,  75.221,  75.959,  76.108,  77.720,  79.306,  80.117,  79.051,  73.398,  70.405,  73.031,  72.626,  69.891,  68.496,  69.016,  64.496,  60.284,  56.164,  50.403,  46.814,  43.598,  40.230,  38.220,  36.595,  37.270,  35.931,  35.872,  34.573,  34.382,  31.848,  30.184,  28.592,  27.367,  26.572,  25.385,  24.167,  22.947,  22.196,  20.102,  17.273, 13617, 09/21/12 23:53:37,   401, Angle Scan32(N), 290.841, 290.341, 290.135, 289.888, 289.601, 289.359, 289.063, 288.816, 288.596, 288.292, 287.907, 286.989, 286.151, 285.159, 283.948, 282.604, 281.604, 280.663, 279.693, 278.789, 278.079, 277.346, 276.519, 275.626, 274.793, 274.033, 272.555, 271.680, 270.758, 269.641, 268.433, 266.921, 265.443, 264.229, 263.036, 261.562, 260.179, 258.611, 257.035, 255.240, 253.437, 251.850, 250.007, 248.111, 246.297, 244.386, 242.365, 240.776, 239.021, 237.268, 235.613, 233.999, 232.464, 230.806, 229.090, 227.562, 226.043, 224.730, 13620, 09/21/12 23:53:38,   Angle Scan32(S),   7.814,   6.994,   6.357,   5.945,   5.634,   5.442,   5.438,   5.371,   5.350,   5.230,   5.403,   4.970,   4.875,   4.949,   5.079,   5.089,   4.678,   4.723,   4.734,   4.826,   4.625,   4.731,   5.251,   5.544,   5.911,   6.282,   7.083,   7.490,   7.369,   6.637,   5.359,   3.880,   2.902,   1.757,   1.279,   1.035,   0.725,   0.560,   0.455,   0.361,   0.275,   0.255,   0.190,   0.162,   0.130,   0.122,   0.103,   0.103,   0.080,   0.080,   0.062,   0.061,   0.056,   0.033,   0.026,   0.032,   0.025,   0.020, 13624, 09/21/12 23:53:39,   403, Angle Scan32(S),   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.001,   0.003,   0.002,   0.003,   0.003,   0.004,   0.006,   0.006,   0.005,   0.005,   0.007,   0.006,   0.003,   0.003,   0.002,   0.004,   0.003,   0.001,   0.001,   0.001,   0.000,   0.001,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.001,   0.001,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.001,   0.001,   0.000,   0.001,   0.002,   0.003,   0.000, 13627, 09/21/12 23:53:40,   404, Angle Scan32(S),  56.426,  52.621,  49.854,  47.596,  47.538,  48.077,  50.507,  49.331,  49.623,  49.122,  51.626,  50.226,  51.898,  55.446,  57.410,  61.732,  58.361,  60.002,  61.793,  65.138,  68.036,  74.196,  82.373,  85.787, 100.000, 100.000, 100.000, 100.000, 100.000, 100.000, 100.000, 100.000, 100.000,  85.190,  66.155,  53.728,  37.351,  23.545,  17.741,  14.367,  12.172,  13.330,  10.572,  10.516,   9.346,   8.075,   6.828,   5.445,   5.651,   5.252,   5.502,   6.274,   6.017,   6.092,   6.767,   6.991,   5.608,   4.837, 13619, 09/21/12 23:53:37,   401, Angle Scan32(A), 290.841, 290.480, 290.186, 289.854, 289.535, 289.214, 288.917, 288.581, 288.361, 288.152, 287.764, 286.828, 286.006, 284.883, 283.694, 282.416, 281.453, 280.518, 279.586, 278.614, 277.817, 277.085, 276.148, 275.167, 274.327, 273.550, 271.972, 270.837, 269.920, 268.786, 267.391, 265.698, 264.125, 263.022, 261.916, 260.413, 259.030, 257.379, 255.820, 253.810, 251.899, 250.295, 248.273, 246.140, 244.078, 242.025, 239.986, 238.294, 236.323, 234.485, 232.698, 230.971, 229.531, 227.863, 226.234, 224.886, 223.635, 222.540, 13622, 09/21/12 23:53:38,   402, Angle Scan32(A),   7.987,   7.424,   6.955,   6.634,   6.380,   6.247,   6.209,   6.208,   6.193,   6.097,   6.195,   5.877,   5.729,   5.754,   5.761,   5.682,   5.312,   5.292,   5.284,   5.308,   5.132,   5.058,   5.182,   5.206,   5.294,   5.250,   5.203,   4.958,   4.590,   4.145,   3.543,   2.837,   2.317,   1.620,   1.235,   1.011,   0.768,   0.615,   0.497,   0.416,   0.336,   0.293,   0.233,   0.196,   0.162,   0.141,   0.123,   0.115,   0.092,   0.091,   0.069,   0.064,   0.054,   0.033,   0.026,   0.032,   0.026,   0.021, 13625, 09/21/12 23:53:39,   403, Angle Scan32(A),   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.001,   0.000,   0.000,   0.002,   0.003,   0.003,   0.003,   0.004,   0.005,   0.007,   0.006,   0.005,   0.005,   0.008,   0.006,   0.003,   0.003,   0.002,   0.004,   0.003,   0.001,   0.001,   0.001,   0.000,   0.001,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.001,   0.001,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.001,   0.001,   0.000,   0.001,   0.002,   0.003,   0.000, 13628, 09/21/12 23:53:40,   404, Angle Scan32(A),  56.682,  53.972,  51.892,  50.578,  50.563,  50.727,  52.154,  52.163,  52.709,  52.844,  54.714,  54.856,  56.689,  60.229,  62.028,  64.870,  63.262,  65.752,  68.310,  71.277,  73.323,  76.555,  79.852,  81.290,  88.961,  92.860, 100.000, 100.000, 100.000, 100.000, 100.000,  99.377,  92.961,  72.472,  62.030,  54.508,  43.265,  32.818,  27.337,  23.694,  21.524,  22.368,  19.811,  19.031,  18.017,  16.873,  15.321,  13.403,  13.020,  12.580,  12.825,  13.851,  13.301,  13.059,  13.511,  13.757,  11.592,  10.430, 290.841,  54.570, 992.600, 224.970,   0.000, BACIC_, No ,belraw3110.0,belsum  -1.8,fdsum   0.0,fdsnow   0.0,yksum  -3.5,ykcsum   0.0,S78D-  OK  ,PARtotal 147.7,ParCnt   0.0,Counter 594.0,Max_ws   6.4,Dir 172.0,Delta_ws   4.6,gust   0.0
2012Sep212358 23:57:03.06250, AAA_YMDHMS, 2012, 9, 21, 23, 57, 4, POSS_71,      OK  ,  15.0,   73.2,   0.0,   0.0,   C,   0.0,   0.3,   0.6,PS711 78:218:17:42 390.3 297.2   64         .1        2.1 60  15  49  73.2   0.0     2080,PS712,PS713,PS714,PS715,PS716 F# 49 2.03 2.14 1.03 2.01 1.07 19.2  0.2 12.4 64  14.7 C    376 0.00 0.00 0  0  3  1  64  0.1 390.3 297.2 149.0 176.3 83.8 32.0 944.0 2.3 0.0 -99.0 0.0 10.7 10.7 10000000.0 376 T 1 I 0 ,dia  2 5, 26 20 3,dia  3 4, 26 20 3,dia  4 6 22 18, 1 0 0 1 0 1,dia  5 4 15 20 3 0, 1,dia  6 4 15 8 4,dia  7 8 14 7,dia  8 4 7 6 0 0 1,dia  9 4 9 4,dia  10 3 7,dia  11 3 1 1,dia  12 1 3,dia  14 2 2,dia  15 1 3,dia  16 1 2 1,dia  17 4 2,dia  21 1,dia  22 0 1,dia  23 2 1,dia  25 0 1,dia  26 1,dia  27 1,dia  29 1,dia  30 1 1,dia  31 1,dia  32 2,dia  33 1 1,dia  34 0 2,dia  36 0 1,dia  37 1 2,dia  38 1 1,dia  39 0 2,dia  40 0 0 1,dia  41 3 3 1,dia  42 1,dia  43 2 0 1,dia  45 1 1,dia  47 0 1,dia  48 1 1,dia  55 1,dia  59 1,dia ,dia ,dia ,dia ,dia ,dia ,dia ,dia ,dia ,dia ,dia ,dia ,dia ,dia ,dia ,dia ,dia ,dia ,dia ,dia ,dia ,dia ,dia ,dia , YANKEE_S/N_0706011,      OK  ,  55.7,  56.8,  -1.2,  17.0,   3.2, 1.000,  -0.9,   0.0,   0.0,  -0.1,  -1.5,  -3.5,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0, CT25K_S/N_A42101,      OK  ,CT0,20,2,3,00, /////, /////, /////,00000300,100,N,100,25,82,206,-4,7,LF7HN1,6,-2,6,5,5,4,4,4,3,4,3,2,2,3,3,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,3,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,3,4,5,6,2,5,4,5,3,3,4,5,4,2,4,3,2,4,5,3,4,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, FD12P_S/N ,      OK  ,  FD, 102, 20517, 16565, C,   0,   0,   0,     0.00,    41.18,    0.0,  0.000,  0.000,  0.000,  0.000,  0.000,  0.000, 15.20,      4, BEL_RAIN,      OK  ,  0.00, -0.20, -1.40, -1.80, -1.40, -1.40, -1.40, 311.0, ,          ,      0,0.0000000,0.0000000, Snow11_Icing ,   OK  , 33, 0909, 182, 17.07, 11111, F8, WS425_SN_,      OK  , 202, 197, 5, 5,   8.5,   8.5,   8.9,   4.4,   4.6,   5.2, 196.6,   6.4, 172.0,   3.6, 198.0,   6.4, 172.0,   2.0, 178.0,   4.4,   6.0,  0,   0.0,   1.2, CR3000_SN_,      OK  , "2012-09-21 20:02:30", "SN_1838", 12.91, 16.45, 17.06, 49.96,1001.1,  0.00,  0.00,2419.4, 432.0,   -4.4,   3.2, 206.6, S78D_SN_,      OK  ,64628.0,64977.0,   8.0, 211.6,   4.3, 207.1,   4.6,   5.4, 209.8,   3.2, 190.3,   5.4, 214.3,   1.6, 191.1,   3.8,  23.2,  0,   0.0,   0.8, PARS_SN ,      OK  ,  0.00, 147.7,    C,   -10.0,   9999,  19.0, 10059,     0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, TB_SN_ ,      OK  ,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0, GEONOR_SN_,      OK  ,  -0.2,  -0.2,   0.0,  -0.5, MP3000_SN_3031,      OK  , 13611, 09/21/12 23:52:03,   201, 290.8410,  54.5700, 992.6000, 224.9700,   0.0000, 13616, 09/21/12 23:52:52,   301,   2.006,   0.000,  -1.000, 13629, 09/21/12 23:53:40,   301,   2.153,   0.000,  -1.000, 13612, 09/21/12 23:52:49,   401, Zenith33, 290.841, 290.619, 290.324, 289.965, 289.594, 289.315, 289.019, 288.657, 288.252, 287.874, 287.473, 286.550, 285.484, 284.489, 283.557, 282.448, 281.549, 280.729, 279.510, 278.444, 277.386, 276.560, 275.714, 275.025, 274.243, 273.660, 272.269, 270.575, 269.615, 268.371, 267.229, 265.628, 264.201, 262.967, 261.651, 259.787, 258.405, 256.936, 255.301, 253.573, 251.715, 249.948, 248.309, 246.431, 244.513, 242.739, 240.876, 238.979, 237.113, 235.236, 233.310, 231.360, 229.586, 227.806, 226.248, 224.444, 222.997, 221.686, 13613, 09/21/12 23:52:50,   402, Zenith33,   8.112,   7.620,   7.356,   7.167,   7.001,   6.926,   6.905,   6.821,   6.749,   6.753,   6.634,   6.261,   5.949,   5.797,   5.612,   5.539,   5.345,   5.309,   5.308,   5.128,   4.854,   4.559,   4.412,   4.302,   4.119,   3.899,   3.280,   2.939,   2.634,   2.426,   2.251,   2.077,   1.768,   1.456,   1.191,   1.016,   0.836,   0.688,   0.572,   0.498,   0.420,   0.342,   0.315,   0.268,   0.247,   0.216,   0.169,   0.151,   0.117,   0.086,   0.079,   0.057,   0.043,   0.034,   0.027,   0.029,   0.025,   0.023, 13614, 09/21/12 23:52:50,   403, Zenith33,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.001,   0.001,   0.001,   0.002,   0.003,   0.004,   0.004,   0.005,   0.006,   0.006,   0.006,   0.005,   0.005,   0.006,   0.006,   0.006,   0.005,   0.004,   0.005,   0.007,   0.001,   0.001,   0.001,   0.001,   0.001,   0.001,   0.000,   0.001,   0.003,   0.001,   0.001,   0.002,   0.004,   0.001,   0.001,   0.004,   0.002,   0.002,   0.001,   0.000,   0.002,   0.000,   0.000,   0.002,   0.001, 13615, 09/21/12 23:52:51,   404, Zenith33,  56.270,  53.729,  53.026,  52.810,  52.940,  53.694,  54.346,  54.964,  55.335,  56.838,  57.384,  58.904,  60.251,  62.294,  63.354,  65.906,  66.386,  69.111,  73.093,  75.221,  75.959,  76.108,  77.720,  79.306,  80.117,  79.051,  73.398,  70.405,  73.031,  72.626,  69.891,  68.496,  69.016,  64.496,  60.284,  56.164,  50.403,  46.814,  43.598,  40.230,  38.220,  36.595,  37.270,  35.931,  35.872,  34.573,  34.382,  31.848,  30.184,  28.592,  27.367,  26.572,  25.385,  24.167,  22.947,  22.196,  20.102,  17.273, 13617, 09/21/12 23:53:37,   401, Angle Scan32(N), 290.841, 290.341, 290.135, 289.888, 289.601, 289.359, 289.063, 288.816, 288.596, 288.292, 287.907, 286.989, 286.151, 285.159, 283.948, 282.604, 281.604, 280.663, 279.693, 278.789, 278.079, 277.346, 276.519, 275.626, 274.793, 274.033, 272.555, 271.680, 270.758, 269.641, 268.433, 266.921, 265.443, 264.229, 263.036, 261.562, 260.179, 258.611, 257.035, 255.240, 253.437, 251.850, 250.007, 248.111, 246.297, 244.386, 242.365, 240.776, 239.021, 237.268, 235.613, 233.999, 232.464, 230.806, 229.090, 227.562, 226.043, 224.730, 13620, 09/21/12 23:53:38,   402, Angle Scan32(N),   8.160,   7.857,   7.577,   7.363,   7.180,   7.123,   7.047,   7.133,   7.134,   7.075,   7.083,   6.916,   6.715,   6.682,   6.530,   6.323,   5.999,   5.897,   5.845,   5.772,   5.604,   5.312,   5.007,   4.764,   4.590,   4.224,   3.621,   3.104,   2.680,   2.432,   2.241,   2.012,   1.820,   1.490,   1.207,   1.003,   0.830,   0.694,   0.557,   0.489,   0.417,   0.340,   0.290,   0.240,   0.203,   0.165,   0.148,   0.128,   0.105,   0.104,   0.077,   0.066,   0.051,   0.031,   0.026,   0.032,   0.027,   0.023, 13623, 09/21/12 23:53:39,   403, Angle Scan32(N),   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.001,   0.001,   0.001,   0.002,   0.003,   0.003,   0.003,   0.004,   0.005,   0.007,   0.006,   0.005,   0.005,   0.008,   0.007,   0.004,   0.003,   0.002,   0.004,   0.003,   0.001,   0.001,   0.001,   0.000,   0.001,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.001,   0.001,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.001,   0.001,   0.000,   0.001,   0.002,   0.003,   0.000, 13626, 09/21/12 23:53:40,   404, Angle Scan32(N),  57.019,  55.193,  53.564,  53.315,  53.339,  53.281,  53.637,  55.162,  56.061,  56.732,  57.804,  59.747,  61.663,  65.110,  66.650,  67.988,  67.915,  70.569,  73.641,  75.918,  76.393,  76.266,  74.408,  74.010,  74.288,  73.384,  70.577,  66.022,  65.699,  65.979,  65.527,  66.482,  68.845,  60.866,  56.617,  53.351,  47.036,  41.541,  38.110,  35.401,  34.460,  33.999,  33.480,  31.319,  31.345,  31.507,  30.179,  28.661,  26.417,  26.580,  26.578,  27.422,  26.442,  25.451,  24.835,  25.084,  22.074,  20.811, 13618, 09/21/12 23:53:37,   401, Angle Scan32(S), 290.841, 290.626, 290.240, 289.821, 289.469, 289.065, 288.771, 288.341, 288.121, 288.010, 287.614, 286.667, 285.864, 284.613, 283.457, 282.245, 281.322, 280.393, 279.502, 278.463, 277.581, 276.853, 275.805, 274.735, 273.891, 273.092, 271.414, 270.019, 269.101, 267.951, 266.361, 264.487, 262.818, 261.826, 260.810, 259.275, 257.892, 256.162, 254.619, 252.395, 250.385, 248.765, 246.572, 244.208, 241.912, 239.723, 237.677, 235.897, 233.725, 231.819, 229.917, 228.090, 226.747, 225.073, 223.535, 222.356, 221.359, 220.467, 13621, 09/21/12 23:53:38,   402, Angle Scan32(S),   7.814,   6.994,   6.357,   5.945,   5.634,   5.442,   5.438,   5.371,   5.350,   5.230,   5.403,   4.970,   4.875,   4.949,   5.079,   5.089,   4.678,   4.723,   4.734,   4.826,   4.625,   4.731,   5.251,   5.544,   5.911,   6.282,   7.083,   7.490,   7.369,   6.637,   5.359,   3.880,   2.902,   1.757,   1.279,   1.035,   0.725,   0.560,   0.455,   0.361,   0.275,   0.255,   0.190,   0.162,   0.130,   0.122,   0.103,   0.103,   0.080,   0.080,   0.062,   0.061,   0.056,   0.033,   0.026,   0.032,   0.025,   0.020, 13624, 09/21/12 23:53:39,   403, Angle Scan32(S),   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.001,   0.003,   0.002,   0.003,   0.003,   0.004,   0.006,   0.006,   0.005,   0.005,   0.007,   0.006,   0.003,   0.003,   0.002,   0.004,   0.003,   0.001,   0.001,   0.001,   0.000,   0.001,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.001,   0.001,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.001,   0.001,   0.000,   0.001,   0.002,   0.003,   0.000, 13627, 09/21/12 23:53:40,   404, Angle Scan32(S),  56.426,  52.621,  49.854,  47.596,  47.538,  48.077,  50.507,  49.331,  49.623,  49.122,  51.626,  50.226,  51.898,  55.446,  57.410,  61.732,  58.361,  60.002,  61.793,  65.138,  68.036,  74.196,  82.373,  85.787, 100.000, 100.000, 100.000, 100.000, 100.000, 100.000, 100.000, 100.000, 100.000,  85.190,  66.155,  53.728,  37.351,  23.545,  17.741,  14.367,  12.172,  13.330,  10.572,  10.516,   9.346,   8.075,   6.828,   5.445,   5.651,   5.252,   5.502,   6.274,   6.017,   6.092,   6.767,   6.991,   5.608,   4.837, 13619, 09/21/12 23:53:37,   401, Angle Scan32(A), 290.841, 290.480, 290.186, 289.854, 289.535, 289.214, 288.917, 288.581, 288.361, 288.152, 287.764, 286.828, 286.006, 284.883, 283.694, 282.416, 281.453, 280.518,
```

Comment: Use `grep -E` or `egrep` (which are the same) to enable extended regexp patterns. Otherwise you would have to escape the basic meta-characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate your regular expressions by giving multiple `-e`:

```
grep -e '^2012Sep' -e '^FD12P.*PARS$' file.dat
```

Also, from your last comment in the previous answer I gather that you do not only want to find the lines that match, but also extract whatever matched.

With gnu grep, you can use the `-o` flag:

```
grep -oe '^2012Sep' -e '^FD12P.*PARS$' file.dat
```

**Edit:**

Given that you want to find all lines that start with 2012Sep and contains FD12P and PARS, and only output specific parts. [`sed`](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) makes more sense in this case:

```
sed -ne 's#^\(2012Sep[^ ]*\).*\(FD12P.*\)PARS.*#\1,\2#p' file.dat | sed -e 's#  *# #g'
```

- `-n` tells sed not to echo line by default
- the `p` flag tells sed to output line when line matched
- the parentheses create groups of the data you want to keep
- \1 and \2 reference the groups
- we match on the full line (the .* around the data we want), meanin only our replacement will remain

Comment: Thanks for your reply. the first row should look line 2012Sep212357, FD12P blah blah PARS and many rows to follow. Your solution prints only the 2012Sep and not FD12P blah blah PARS. I also used grep -oe '^2012Sep.*AAA$' -e '^FD12P.*PARS$' file.dat it doesn't print anything and when I try same as above with >out.dat (or txt). the output file is empty.

Comment: Updated the answer according to explanation.

Comment: thanks for your help. I get the following error  sed:-e expression #1, char 47: unterminated 's' command

Comment: i put an example of how the output should look like (above in the question).

Comment: getting error sed: -e expression #1, char 45: unterminated 's' command

Comment: error sed:-e expression #1, char 45: unterminated 's' command

Comment: Not sure what version of sed you have, works on mac and linux for me. Try with slashes instead of hash:
`sed -ne 's/^\(2012Sep[^ ]*\).*\(FD12P.*\)PARS.*/\1,\2/p' file.dat | sed -e 's/  */ /g'`

Comment: Danne, it worked. Forgot to put a sapce after [* ]. Now, at the end of the command i put >test.txt but it only put the first line and not rest of the rows.

Comment: OK. I've tried it with the two lines you provided, and they both turn up in the file, so the rest of your lines must be different somehow. See if they really have all the strings (2012Sep, FD12P, PARS), and that they appear in that order.

Comment: Danne is a genius...I sincerely can't thank you enough. U rock!

Comment: I am facing another problem. The code works, but it puts a space between every character. When open the output file in excel, it can NOT perform any statistics due to the space (e.g. the 3.5 is 3 . 5). How to fix the code to remove this space between every character?

Comment: @user2153702, as per my answer to your subsequent question, this is because you've used `s#X*#X#` (zero or more spaces, where `X` indicates a space) as the second `sed` string rather than `s#XX*#X#` (one or more spaces). This answer is actually correct, you just transcribed the solution wrongly.

Answer (score 2):

You have two distinct operations here. The first is the selection of lines, limiting yourself to only those starting with `2012Sep` and containing the strings `FD12P` and `, PARS` (in that order).

The second is the filtering on each of those lines to keep only the date and the text between `FDP12` and `PARS` (excluding the `PARS` itself).

The first operation can be done with a `grep` in the pipeline, the second can be done with a `sed`:

```
grep '^2012Sep.*, FD12P.*, PARS' infile.dat
    | sed -e 's/ .*, FD12P/, FD12P/'
          -e 's/, PARS.*$//'
    >outfile.dat
```

This relies on a few things which you should check.

- the date is immediately followed by a space;
- there is only one `FDP12` and `PARS` in the line;
- the `FD12P` and `PARS` is always preceded by `", "` (comma, space).

If any of those turn out to be not true, you may need to tweak the arguments to `grep` and `sed`. That's of particular concern if the second rule is violated since you then have to specify in more detail how you want it to behave.

The following transcript shows this in action:

```
pax> cat qq.in
2012Sep212357 23:56, AAA_YMDHMS, FD12P_S/N , blah, PARS, more blah
a dummy line which should not match
2012Sep212358 23:57, AAA_YMDHMS, FD12P_S/N , yada, PARS_xyzzy, more yada

pax> grep '^2012Sep.*FD12P.*, PARS' qq.in
...> | sed -e 's/ .*FD12P/, FD12P/' -e 's/, PARS.*$//'
2012Sep212357, FD12P_S/N , blah
2012Sep212358, FD12P_S/N , yada
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it and it does not yield as your answer. Don't know what I am doing wrong!

Comment: It copies the entire file! I just wanted the date/time, FD12P blah blah, PARS

Comment: It should look like rows of date/time,FD12P blahblah, PARS.

Comment: @user2153702, you state in the comment that PARS is required to be left in yet your sample output suggests not. I have chosen the latter rule but it's easy enough to adjust to the former if need be.

Comment: Dear Paxdiable, thanks for your help. I tried DanneJ's code and it worked. Haven't tired yours as I don't have a linux box on my right now. The problem with Danne's code is that it puts a space between each charachter in each row. When I open outfile.dat (or txt) in excel, I can't perform any statistics due to the space (e.g. 3.5 looks like 3 . 5). Is there a way to fix the code to remove the space?

Comment: @user2153702, yes there is. Your best bet, though, is to post that as a separate question so as to keep to the intent of SO. I _could_ answer in this little comment box but then it would be useful only to you rather than everybody.

Comment: will try to post a new question now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352392/linux-grep-sed-certain-lines-spae-removal

Comment: Dear Paxdiable, I have posted a new question and look forward to your fix. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352392/linux-grep-sed-certain-lines-space-removal